# How to expose your test database in a java web application? Simple Sqlsheet servlet?

Tags: java, database, servlets, web-applications, hsqldb

I have a java web application which i'm developing using a local embedded HSQL database. Is there kind of a servlet which I can plug-in into my application and expose it /dbconsole, where I can fire sql statements, inspect tables, fields and table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) which is a fast java opensource database. It can be easily embedded and it has a build-in servlet (org.h2.server.web.WebServlet) for db admin usage. We have used it in our production several years and it is very stable.

Here's its web console UI rendered by org.h2.server.web.WebServlet: 
[image: H2 web console]